# Hacer merge de 3 archivos en uno

Tags: ingenieria-del-software, archivo-de-propiedades, attached-properties

os cuento un poco mi duda, tenemos 3 personas distintas que hacer cambios en un mismo archivo de `properties`, y luego unirlo todo en uno respetando los cambios que ha hecho cada uno, no podemos usar la consola ni merge ni nada, ¿alguien conoce algún software para la causa?

Comment: Porque no puedes usar Merge?

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido que puedan modificar algo sin tener consola ni "nada" que puedan usar para el merge

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres depender de git o cualquier otro software de control de versiones para hacer el merge y sólo van a ser 3 usuarios, puedes utilizar KDiff3 para hacer merge de las versiones cargándolas a mano, pero sería infinitamente más sencillo hacerlo con git

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/